# group by validation rule, not by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery with the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plug-in to validate a form. I'm also using jQuery-ui's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) to provide a list of acceptable values for one of the fields. Two fields, `prov_type` and `prov_date` control the content of the autocomplete list. `prov_type` is a radio button and `prov_date` is a text input with [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) attached.

### Goals

1. Show message from failed `hasantecedent` rule in a different place from normal rules
2. Show `hasantecedent` failure message only once, even though it applies to 2 fields

### Problem

I have added `prov_type` and `prov_date` to `$.validator.groups` as "hasant" which accomplishes the second goal. The issue is that they are really only a group for the `hasantecedent` rule. Any other rules applied to them (e.g. date validation on `prov_date`) should really act as though the elements weren't grouped. I *think* this probably can be addressed either in `errorPlacement` or in `showError` but I can't figure out how.

Ideas?

### Code

#### validation defaults

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    ignore: ":hidden", // do not validate form fields in invisible sections
    focusCleanup: true,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        //something here to determine for placement of group rules?

        if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
        }else if(element.is(":checkbox") && element.parent().is('li')){
            error.insertBefore(element.closest("ul.horiz"));
        }else{
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
        };
    },
    success:'checked',// set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    validClass:'checked'//set this to same so valid class will be removed from fields that become errors
});
```

#### hasantecedent rule

```
$.validator.addMethod("hasantecedent", function( value, element ) {
    set_possible_antecedents();
    var type=$('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val();

    var r = $('#prov_date').data(type).length;
    if(r){
        $('.antecedent',$('#'+ type)).removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('.antecedent',$('#'+ type)).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

    return r;
}, 'No fish are available for the current provenance date.');
```

#### form validation

```
$("form[name='provenance']").validate({
    onkeyup: function(element, event){ //no keyup validation for fields with UI widgets
        if(jQuery.inArray( element.name,['prov_date','dam', 'sire','reuse'])>-1) return;
         $.validator.defaults.onkeyup.call(this, element, event);
    },
    groups:{hasant: 'prov_type prov_date'},
    rules: {
        prov_type: {hasantecedent: {depends: function(e){ return jQuery.inArray( $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val(),['cross','reuse']) > -1;}}},
        prov_date: {
            dateCan:true,
            hasantecedent: {
                depends: function(e){return jQuery.inArray( $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val(),['cross','reuse']) > -1;}
            }
        },
        fish_id: { required: true, pkey: true},
        dam_id: {
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            pkey: true
        },
        sire_id: {
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            pkey: true
        },
        dam: {
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            isantecedent: {
                depends: function(e){return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';}
            }
        },
        sire:{
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            isantecedent: {
                depends: function(e){return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';}
            },
        },
        dam_count: {
            digits: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            min:0
        },
        sire_count: {
            digits: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='cross';},
            min:0
        },
        supplier_id:{
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='delivery';},
            pkey: true
        },
        removal_id:{
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='reuse';},
            pkey: true
        },
        removal: {
            required: function(e) {return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='reuse';},
            isantecedent: {
                depends: function(e){return $('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val()=='reuse';}
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up having to do is remove the `hasant` group, add a static `#hasant` div where the message could go, and add a toggle vis to the `hasantecedent` rule. Like this:

## javascript

```
$.validator.addMethod("hasantecedent", function( value, element ) {
    set_possible_antecedents();
    var type=$('input[name="prov_type"]:checked').val();
    var r = $('#prov_date').data(type).length;
    if(r){
        $('input.antecedent').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('warning');
        $( "#hasant" ).hide();
    } else {
        $('input.antecedent').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('warning');
                $( "#hasant" ).show();
    }
    return r;
},  ' ');
```

## css

```
#hasant {
    display:none;
    color:#C7252B;
    border: 2px solid #C7252B;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:65%;
    width: 15em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

## html

```
<div id='hasant'>No fish are available for the current provenance date.</div>
```